Post message won't send a click
I've been trying for months to get a click without moving mouse
Why isn't this working?
It's like this click just doesn't register, I'm at an absolute loss:
import win32gui
import win32api
import win32con
import time
from win32gui import GetWindowText, GetForegroundWindow


def control_click(x, y, handle, button='left'):

    l_param = win32api.MAKELONG(x, y)

    if button == 'left':
        win32gui.PostMessage(handle, win32con.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, win32con.MK_LBUTTON, l_param)
        win32gui.PostMessage(handle, win32con.WM_LBUTTONUP, win32con.MK_LBUTTON, l_param)

    elif button == 'right':
        win32gui.PostMessage(handle, win32con.WM_RBUTTONDOWN, 0, l_param)
        win32gui.PostMessage(handle, win32con.WM_RBUTTONUP, 0, l_param)
        

print(GetWindowText(GetForegroundWindow()))
time.sleep(2)
h = GetForegroundWindow()
time.sleep(1)
print("click")
control_click(264, 74, h)
time.sleep(10)


If the answer was correct and helped you out, could you mark it as correct ?

Your control_click function is not defined correctly: it should simulate a mouse click at the given coordinates:
import win32gui
import win32api
import win32con
import time
from win32gui import GetWindowText, GetForegroundWindow

def control_click(x, y, handle, button='left'):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x, y))
    if button == 'left':
        win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0)
        win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0, 0)
    elif button == 'right':
        win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0)
        win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, x, y, 0, 0)
print(GetWindowText(GetForegroundWindow()))
time.sleep(2)
h = GetForegroundWindow()
time.sleep(1)
print("click")
control_click(264, 74, h)
time.sleep(10)

Now, control_click 1st moves the cursor to the specified coordinates using win32api.SetCursorPos then it simulates a mouse click at those coordinates depending on the argument input it will simulate left or right accordingly.

That works but i really wanted to do without moving my cursor? is it possible?

I have to look it up, don't know how to implement it as of yet.
